# Using quotes inside brackets - PHP / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, row

Hello I read a while that it is safer use single quotes inside brackets instead of not doing, is it true?

```
echo $row[0];
echo $row[id];
```

or

```
echo $row['0'];
echo $row['id'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because you might have:

```
define("id", "something else");

$row = array(
    "id" => 5,
    "something else" => "foobar"
);

echo $row["id"]; // 5
echo $row[id]; // foobar
```

Also in `E_STRICT` mode `$row[id]` will give you a warning. This is why you should always develop with `E_STRICT` on. Turn it on by placing `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` at the top of your script.

`$row[0]` and `$row["0"]` are equivalent, you can use these as you see fit (indexed array vs. associative array?)

Answer (score 1):

- Your first example:  `[0]` or `['0']`

  This does not need quotes, because the key is numeric.
- Your second example:  `[id]` or `['id']`

  This definitely should have quotes. The variant without quotes is a legacy feature in PHP that really shouldn't be used any more.

  If you do not include the quotes, you are actually telling PHP to use a `define()` named `id`, rather than the string `id`. In most cases this works, because PHP has a feature where if you specify a define that doesn't exist, it assumes the string equivalent, rather than throwing an error. (This is one of PHP's worst design decisions, but that's beside the point here)

  The point is that in most cases it will do exactly the same either way. The version without quotes will run slower because it needs to search for the define and do the string conversion when it doesn't find it, but it won't be that much slower; you won't notice it.

  The real danger is if somewhere else in your code you do create a define with the same name -- eg:

  ```
   define('id','blahblah');
  ```

  Now PHP will see `$var[id]` as being `$var['blahblah']`, which will break your code.

  It's not always easy to know when a define will be used -- especially if you're including third-party libraries -- which means that while your code without the quotes may work now, there is no knowing when it might suddenly break, without you being able to work out why.

  So the recommendation is to *always* use quotes for an array element name when it's a string.

Answer (score 0):

A quote denotes a string literal, while unquoted denotes either an integer or a constant.

If you're looking for a named array key in an associative array, usually you want to use the string literal. I.E `$row['id']` rather than `$row[id]` (which should not work).

If you're looking for a numeric array key a string will be cast to an integer. So `$row['0']` should evaluate to `$row[0]`. Still, I think it's a better practice to use an actual integer (`$row[0]`). I'm not sure if there's an actual performance hit due to the variable casting, but it's better to use the correct data type for readability and accuracy.

Comment: `$row[id]` works because it's interpreted as `"id"`, it does throw an `E_WARNING` though.